# SQL join query - join instead of inline query

Tags: mysql

I would like to use join instead of inline queries but the one I was able to make is giving wrong values.
Please check this link - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57cad/9

It has 2 individual queries which give correct values and a join query which gives an incorrect result.

Can someone please help...

Comment: The problem is that you have 3 records being recorded on logsmaincontrols_campaigns_daily_stats for a single accountpayments. The join is giving all the possible permutations, hence each matching record on accountpayments is being counted 3 times. You will probably need to join against sub queries to get the results you want

Comment: Will using subqueries be more efficient than using JOINS?

Comment: Problem is that you don't really have a choice. Sub queries are generally less efficient (especially correlated ones) than joins, but you are landing up with some rows coming back multiple times, hence adding to the results multiple time.

Comment: Hmm....I'll go with subqueries for now. It is getting the job done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer shown here: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57cad/78)

Your queries could be improved upon in a few areas which make their JOINing a little more obvious.

In your first query, a better version has the the GROUP BY clause's columns listed in the SELECT clause and your HAVING clause (while working) becomes the WHERE clause (IMO: The best practice is to use aggregate function only in the HAVING clause:)

```
SELECT usercode, ROUND(coalesce(sum(paymentamount)*0.99,0),2) AS payment 
FROM accountpayments 
WHERE usercode = 21
GROUP BY usercode;
```

Your second query can be rewritten as a JOIN (vs. the subquery)

```
SELECT campaigns.usercode, ROUND(coalesce(sum(lmc_cds.total_spending),0),2) AS total_spending 
FROM logsmaincontrols_campaigns_daily_stats AS lmc_cds 
JOIN campaigns
  ON campaigns.campcode = lmc_cds.campcode
WHERE campaigns.usercode = 21;
```

Since the queries don't share any tables, I decided to JOIN the queries to each other as derived tables using the usercode as the JOINing column.

```
SELECT t1.usercode, t1.payment, t2.total_spending
FROM (SELECT usercode, ROUND(coalesce(sum(paymentamount)*0.99,0),2) AS payment 
      FROM accountpayments 
      WHERE usercode = 21
      GROUP BY usercode) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT campaigns.usercode, ROUND(coalesce(sum(lmc_cds.total_spending),0),2) AS total_spending 
      FROM logsmaincontrols_campaigns_daily_stats AS lmc_cds 
      JOIN campaigns
        ON campaigns.campcode = lmc_cds.campcode
      WHERE campaigns.usercode = 21) AS t2
  ON t1.usercode = t2.usercode;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The first 2 queries are just there to show what values for payment and total spending are correct.  I just want the result with usercode, payment, total spending and budgetstatus (from campaigns table; forgot to include it).  Your query does give the correct output but I am a bit apprehensive about inline queries as you have used....  can it not be done avoiding inline/subqueries?